# arraylist iterator equals returns java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, exception, arraylist, iterator

```
while(it.hasNext())
{
    System.out.println("List: " +it.next().getProduct().getName() + " " + product.getName());
                
    if (it.next().getProduct().getName().equals(product.getName())) 
    {
        System.out.println("asd");
    }
}
```

It returns exactly the same thing:

> List: Apple Apple
>
> List: Orange Orange

But when I try to compare them I get

> List: Orange Orange
>
> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.NoSuchElementException

and the problem is in the if () line.. It doesn't matter if I compare them with or without getName() (as they're the same objects..) Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should call the `next()` method only once on each iteration. It moves the cursor to the next element on each call of the `next()` method. You don't want to do that, to make sure that `hasNext()` is executed before each invocation of the `next()`, to avoid going past the last element.

It would be something as follows

```
Product p = it.next();
//and use p onwards
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Product temp = null; // might break your equals if written badly
while ( it.hasNext() ) {
    // get next product
    Product product = it.next().getProduct(); // use this when you need to refer to "next" product

    if ( product.equals( temp ) ) { // compare previous product (temp) with this product
         // do something
    }

    temp = product; // set temp equal to current product, on next iteration it is last
}
```

Answer (score 0):

each next() call moves the iterator forward. You call it twice in the code. So either add hasnext() infront of the second next() or remove the second call of next()